# How to remove space between print and user num

Tags: python

old newbie in Python, and I came across a problem.

```
print('Adding the two numbers gives',user_num,', which is different from',str(number1 + number2),'.')
```

output:

```
Adding the two numbers gives 24 , which is different from 1212 .
```

Question: How do you remove the space between `24` and the comma, and the space between `1212` and `.`?

Comment: DSM's answer to the duplicate questions covers most of the options. If you're using Python 3.6 or later, the one you want is probably the f-string: `print(f'Adding the two numbers gives {user_num}, which is different from {number1 + number2}.')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a separator to `print` with the `sep` keyword argument. To remove separators altogether, make it an empty string.

```
print(number1, number2, sep='')
```